# load wave file data into a buffer

Tags: c

gcc 4.4.2
c89

I have a wave file:
8000 Hz
16 bit

I am wondering if there anyway I can load the raw data of this wave file into a buffer.

Many thanks for any advice

Comment: How is it different from loading any file into a buffer?

Comment: If you want the sample data, there are fields in the header which specify the offset to the sample data and its length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're looking for reading a binary file in C. 
Something like this:

```
FILE* f;
char buf[MAX_FILE_SIZE];
int n;

f = fopen("filename.bin", "rb");
if (f)
{
    n = fread(buf, sizeof(char), MAX_FILE_SIZE, f);
}
else
{
    // error opening file
}
```

This reads a buffer of *bytes*. From it you can build your data. Reading multi-byte data directly is more tricky because you run into issues of representation and endianness.

Two key C functions are used:

- `fopen` that opens a file in binary mode (the "rb" flag)
- `fread` that reads block data (useful for binary streams). Documented [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/).

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by representation and endianness?

Comment: @robUK: I mean - how are multi-byte values stored in the memory (which is an array of bytes, basically). Endianness is an important issue you must read about - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process the sound samples, you would be best to use a library that interprets the sound data for you. For example [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/).

Answer (score 1):

The best way IMHO would be to use a linked list with elements holding a large(1024 or more) fixed size char arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This project dump WAVE file data to a csv file. You can hack into it and get the array which is dumped to csv file.

https://github.com/dilawar/sound

Disclaimer: I am author of this repository.